# JS Image Slider For Loop not iterating on second iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

guys i've been trying to solve this for the last couple of days. I really need your help and I want to understand whats going on. My Function will iterate once and the go back to the first value, how can I make it so that the loops starts from zero and keeps on looping.  I've tried while loops but thos attempts have been unsuccessful.  Thank you guys!

```
function run() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= imgArray.length; i++) {
        (function (e) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (i == imgArray.length) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                imgContainer.style.background = imgArray[i];

            }, 3000 * e);

        })(i);
    };
}
```

Comment: can you post some html to go with this

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want is a `setInterval`. Unlike `setTimeout` that only executes once, `setInterval` executes at every interval of time (e.g. every 1 sec) until you call `clearInterval()`.

Using this and some modulo (`%`) logic, we can do:

```
var currentImage = 0;

//this will call `changeBackground` every 1 second
setInterval(changeBackground, 1000); //1000 ms = 1 sec

function changeBackground() {
    currentImage = (currentImage + 1) % imgArray.length;
    imgContainer.style.background = imgArray[currentImage];
}
```

---

#### Explanation of the modulo part:

The `%` or modulo gives us the remainder of the Euclidean division of `imgArray.length` by `currentImage + 1`, which will always be a value between 0 and `imgArray.length - 1`. Whenever `currentImage + 1` becomes equal to `imgArray.length`, `currentImage` gets reset to zero.